# How can I debug a Perl script?

Tags: perl, debugging

When I run a Perl script, how can I debug it? For example, in ksh I add the `-x` flag. But how I do the same in Perl?

Answer (score 25):

```
perl -d your_script.pl args
```

is how you debug Perl. It launches you into an interactive `gdb`-style command line debugger.

Comment: Alex's answer has link to documentation for `-d`

Comment: Step 1: add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script. If that doesn't help, go to step 2: use perl -d.

Answer (score 13):

To run your script under the Perl debugger you should use the `-d` switch:

```
perl -d script.pl
```

But Perl is flexible. It supplies some hooks, and you may force the debugger to work as you want

So to use different debuggers you may do:

```
perl -d:DebugHooks::Terminal script.pl
# OR
perl -d:Trepan script.pl
```

Look these modules [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::DebugHooks) and [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan).

There are several most interesting Perl modules that hook into Perl debugger internals: [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) and [Devel::Cover](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover)

And [many others](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Devel%3A%3A&search_type=modules).

Comment: I've found Devel::NYTProf invaluable in identifying and speeding up slow spots in my perl code.

Comment: @MatthewLock Yeah, [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) is amazing thing

Answer (score 10):

If using an interactive debugger is OK for you, you can try [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).

Answer (score 5):

I would also recommend using the [Perl debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).

However, since you asked about something like shell's `-x` have a look at the [Devel::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Trace/) module which does something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) with [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/): It gives you a nice IDE with debugging possibilities, including the ability to place breakpoints and the `Perl Expression View` for inspecting the value of variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do remote debugging (for CGI or if you don't want to mess output with debug command line), use this:

Given test:

```
use v5.14;
say 1;
say 2;
say 3;
```

Start a listener on whatever host and port on terminal 1 (here `localhost:12345`):

```
$ nc -v -l localhost -p 12345
```

For readline support use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/#rlwrap) (you can use on `perl -d` too):

```
$ rlwrap nc -v -l localhost -p 12345
```

And start the test on another terminal (say terminal 2):

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS="RemotePort=localhost:12345" perl -d test
```

Input/Output on terminal 1:

```
Connection from 127.0.0.1:42994

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test:2):    say 1;
  DB<1> n
main::(test:3):    say 2;
  DB<1> select $DB::OUT

  DB<2> n
2
main::(test:4):    say 3;
  DB<2> n
3
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<2>
```

Output on terminal 2:

```
1
```

Note the sentence if you want output on debug terminal

```
select $DB::OUT
```

If you are Vim user, install this plugin: [dbg.vim](https://github.com/albfan/dbg.vim) which provides basic support for Perl.

Comment: https://github.com/albfan/dbg.vim is no longer supporting pdb.

Answer (score 2):

> The most effective debugging tool is still [careful thought](http://web.archive.org/web/20150801105520/http://debuggingbythinking.com/), coupled
>   with judiciously placed print statements.
>
> [Brian Kernighan, "Unix for Beginners" (1979)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Programming)

(And enhancing print statements with [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper))

Comment: Nice little debate here about the perl debugger too http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=48579

Comment: link is dead. Please review your answer

Comment: So in short, Perl wants you to code like it's 1979?

Comment: Here is an even more efficient way to debug: do not program at all. Now, let's go back to the real world.

Comment: I hope you can understand that if people asked anything like "how do I debug perl", that would most likely indicate that the "careful thought" tool failed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [Perldebugger](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) can also be invoked from the scripts shebang line, which is how I mostly use the `-x` flag you refer to, to debug shell scripts.

`#! /usr/bin/perl -d`